# Why does the recursive version run slower?

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

I wrote two versions of a helper function for a leetcode problem. I was surprised to see that the iterative version runs over twice as fast, despite being essentially the same code.

I was assuming that something like this would just be optimized automatically by the compiler, but there is in fast a huge difference in runtimes.

Recursive version (runs in 14ms):

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String word, int left, int right) {
    if(left >= right) return true;
    if(word.charAt(left) != word.charAt(right)) return false;

    return isPalindrome(word, left + 1, right - 1);
}
```

Iterative version (runs in 6ms):

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String word, int left, int right) {
    while(left < right) {
        if(word.charAt(left) != word.charAt(right)) return false;
        
        left++;
        right--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Why does the iterative version run so much faster?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ this surprises you? Iteration doesn't incur the overhead of a completely new function call, with the associated call stack management, and no, the compiler will absolutely not unroll a recursive function call. Again, _why_ did you think that would happen?

Comment: Recursion  has its benefits, but efficiency is not necessarily one of them because of the overhead involved.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans While I know that recursion has the extra overhead, I did not expect it to more than double the runtime. For clarity's sake, it doubled the runtime of the entire program (which this helper function was just one part of). I also expected that this could be something that the compiler could optimize automatically, minimizing the difference between the two.

Comment: Some languages can rewrite tail calls and make them iterative. Java isn't one of them.

Comment: "For clarity's sake, it doubled the runtime of the entire program" what program? You're showing two methods in isolation in your post. If you're asking about runtime, show the [mcve] and _its_ runtime. Showing a runtime that is technically not related to the code you're showing because there's an unknown quantity of additional code that you're not talking about makes for [a questionable question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think that showing the entire program's code is outside the scope of the question. Unless you really want to get into the nitty gritty details of exactly how this helper function is called. The key point is that the helper function greatly increased the runtime of the overall program, and why this is the case.

Comment: I think if the runtime you're showing is for the full program, show the full program. And if that's too much code, then redo the timing using just the code you're showing (with some minimal public static main code that invoke a bunch of calls). Don't show timings for completely different code from what you're showing, it doesn't actually tell us, or yourself, anything.